# SimpleUML - Show the entire name of attributes and methods on class diagram

Tags: android-studio, plugins, uml, diagram

I'm trying to generate classes diagram on Android Studio with SimpleUML plugin
I want to know if there is a way to show the entire nameof attributes and methods on class diagram becouse they are truncated (with an ellipsis)

Here's an example

[image]

Comment: I am also trying to find the solution for this problem, but seems like there is no way for this day. I also cannot find any option in menu ...